# htaccess " Changing URL "

Tags: asp.net, .htaccess, redirect

**I created site with this kind of URL :**

- acma.us/index.aspx
- acma.us/FreeSaleCertificate.aspx

**I have already re-folder all the site files again and i have changed FROM "ASPX To HTML" now it's Now like this:**

- acma.us/Certificate/index.html
- acma.us/Certificate/FreeSaleCertificate.html

**Help Me to make it like this :**

- http://www.acma.us/Certificate/FreeSaleCertificate/

**And tell me how to Make redirect 301 From Old URL To New URL :**

- **From :** acma.us/FreeSaleCertificate.aspx
- **To :** acma.us/Certificate/FreeSaleCertificate/

**Please i need help to do this steps , Im not expert about it :(**

Waiting Someone to help me :)

Thanks & Best Regards :)

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `Certificates/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Certificates/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(?:index)?(.*?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/Certificates/$1\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: What url did you enter in your browser.

Comment: See now, All of my files with aspx has been converted to HTML Already, Now i need to change URL For this HTML File **From :** http://acma.us/Certificate/index11.html **To:** http://acma.us/Certificate/index11/           ...... Thanks & Best Regards @anubhava

Comment: it's not working too, i don't know where is the problem .
I Change the website for testing and same problem 

* http://usachamber.net/Certificates/index.html

* http://usachamber.net/Certificates/freesalecertificate.html

* http://usachamber.net/Certificates/manufacturecertificate.html

I Put The htaccess File In ROOT " usachamber.net/.htaccess "

Comment: I Just Need To Hide This HTML :(

Comment: Is `/Certificates` a real directory?

Comment: Yes It's Folder And inside it " 5 HTML Files "

Comment: ok see updated code and make **it is placed in `/Certificates/.htaccess`**

Comment: Sorry :( , Same Situation

Comment: Can's do much because rules are all fine. Most likely you are either not using Apache or .htaccess isn't enabled.